# Looking for a random statistical biaised function

Tags: probability, random, random-functions

A common random function is designed like a dice, if you call it many times it will yield approximately the same number of times 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. Statistically, you could say it's equally spread or dispersed.

Are there function or formulas that use a random function, and can output an predictable, unequally statistically spread value ?

Imagine I want a function that if I call it, results tend to have 3 times 6s as usual, 2 times 2s as usual, half as many 4s as usual, etc ?

I don't want exactly those weights, but I wonder how is it possible to generate random values that tend to yield more values than others.

Comment: You might want to [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Sampling_from_an_arbitrary_distribution): given "uniform random coins" (access to independent random values uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$), you can generate samples from pretty much any explicit distribution, as biased as it pleases you.

Comment: This might help too: http://dicedcoins.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/simulate-fair-coins-unfair/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after but you could throw the die twice or more and "reinterpret" the results.  For example, if you throw $(1,2)$ call it $1$, if you throw $(2,1)$ call it $3$ etc.  If you interpret the $36$ possibilities as
$$1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6$$
then the probability of $6$ will be $\frac{18}{36}=\frac{1}{2}$, three times as much as usual, the probability of $2$ will be $\frac{12}{36}=\frac{1}{3}$, twice as much as usual and the probability of $4$ will be $\frac{3}{36}=\frac{1}{12}$, half the usual.